# SearchView hint not showing

Tags: android, android-manifest, searchview

I'm trying to display hint text in a search view in my Main Activity. The onqueryTextSubmit launches another activity called SearchResultsActivity which will display the results of the query. My problem is that I cannot display the hint text. My searchable.xml code

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
/>
```

and the manifest code

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable1"
            android:value=".SearchResultsActivity"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable">
        </meta-data>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and finaly my onQueryTextSubmit code

```
@Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {

            Anniversaries tempResults;
            tempResults = mainAnniversariesManager.searchManager.searchAnniversaries(query);

            if (tempResults.entries.size() == 0)
            {
                snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinator), getString(R.string.no_results_found) + query, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackbar.show();
                return true;
            } else
            {
                snackbar = null;
                if (!searchView.isIconified())
                {
                    searchView.setIconified(true);
                }
                menuItem.collapseActionView();

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SearchResultsActivity.class);
                Bundle args=new Bundle();
                args.putSerializable("serialized_Anniversaries",tempResults);
                intent.putExtra("args",args);
                startActivity(intent);

                return false;
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the hint a result of the query?

Comment: I never used searchable but my first suggest is: Maybe the searchable is already filled with empty content so the hint is not shown?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To add SearchView hint text use the following code :

```
search.setQueryHint("Custom Search Hint");
```

Comment: I know that, I was just thinking doing it using the xml configuration. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `mSearchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_search_view); mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Product");` giving me `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SearchView.setQueryHint(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @yian.athanasiadis Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61428756/6269691 for implementing **using the xml configuration**.

Answer (score 30):

try to use 
`app:queryHint="@string/search"
app:defaultQueryHint="@string/search"`

Comment: Thanks, that is what i am exactly looking for.

Comment: Use it where? in the menu.xml file where i set an item as searchView or inside searchable.xml or someplace else?

Answer (score 20):

### Using the XML configuration.

This worked for me :

```
<SearchView
            .
            .
            .
            android:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"    />
```

If the hint's desired to be visible in the **Non-Active State** of SearchView set `android:iconifiedByDefault` to `"false"`.

If it's undesired set `android:iconifiedByDefault` to `"true"`.

Comment: This is the answer without creating a function or code in the Activity. Just add this in the layout.xml.

Comment: I like the bonus of using `iconifiedByDefault`.

Answer (score 4):

## You can use the below two lines of code to show the hint in SearchView.

**1) You can simply add a hint by adding the below line.**

```
android:queryHint="Search Medicines here..."
```

**when you will use the above line then the hint will only appear when you click the search icon.**

**2) If you want to show a hint without clicking the search icon simple add the below line in the search view**

```
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

for me non of the solutions did not work.

I get an instance of the edittext of searchview and then, I set a hint for that.

```
EditText et= (EditText) mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
et.setHint(context.getString(R.string.search));
```

Answer (score 1):

According [Create a Searchable Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#create-sc)

If you're using a `SearchView` as an action view in the app bar, you should associate the searchable configuration with the `SearchView` by calling `setSearchableInfo(SearchableInfo)`.

```
SearchManager sm = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
searchView.setSearchableInfo(sm.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Comment: why is it here? it has nothing to do with query hint text