# How to make SearchView Hint visible before tapping on the view?

Tags: android

I have the following SearchView:

```
<android.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_user_searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Search here"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bg"/>
```

It looks like this before i tap on it (Hint not visible):
[image]

And like this after i tap on it (Hint visible):[image]

How can i make the hint visible before i tap on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SearchView hint not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919328/searchview-hint-not-showing)

Comment: @EliasFazel no the proposed solution does not make the hint appear before tapping on the SearchView